# Show dynamic array data in column of c3js graph

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

How to show array data in column of a graph, that will have any number of values in it

I tried below code, and it is not working:

```
$http.get(getUrl('api/Report/GetDepartmentTargetData') +     "?year="+         $scope.selectYear + "&ideaPerUser=" +      $scope.ideaPerAssociate).then(function (response) {
    $scope.deptChart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            bindto: '#chart',
            x: 'x',
            columns: [
                ['x', response.data.XAxis],
                ['Achievement', response.data.Data]
            ],
            type: 'bar',
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'categorized',
            }
        },

    });
}, function (errors) {

});
```

response of the url that is being called from the angular js, it can be of any length:

```
<DepartmentTargetModel>
    <Data>
        <d2p1:string>0%</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>0%</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>100%</d2p1:string>
    </Data>
    <TargetLine>
        <d2p1:string>72%</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>72%</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>72%</d2p1:string>
    </TargetLine>
    <XAxis>
        <d2p1:string>RBEI/BSW2</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>RBVH/ETI1</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>BetP/BPS</d2p1:string>
    </XAxis>
</DepartmentTargetModel>
```

Comment: I am presuming that _response.data.ListOfValues_ is an ajax response please check if you getting a json array from server.

Comment: yes, i checked and I am getting the response from server.

Comment: Please paste that response instead of the server code

Comment: I modified the question, specific to my problem.